# Creating a 3-D hexagon map

Tags: opengl, hexagonal-tiles

I am trying to create a 3-D hex map. Where the hexagon's match up next and below. like this
[hex map](http://www.c-thru-music.com/cgi/?page=layout_octaves)

A user would enter (x) rows , (X) Columns and it would create a map like that.

I need 3d Due to i would like to be able to stack the hexagons at some point and also texture them, But now to question. How do i draw a hexagon.  I am still pretty new to OpenGL but i have got this to draw a hex

```
   glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for I := 0 to 6 do
begin
  glVertex3f(sin(i/6.0*2*PI),cos(i/6.0*2*pi),-2);
end;
glEnd;
```

not sure thats the best way and its only one face.. But also it just makes one HUGE hexagon. and of course i will need smaller ones.  Any help on how to take this project on would be great!  In the project i have

```
prxleft  = -1
prxRight = 1
prxTop = 1
prxBottom   -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're heading in the right direction.  There are many ways to draw using OpenGL, and while folks will argue this is the the fastest way, it will get you a hexagon on the screen.  To draw multiple hexagons, wrap your `glBegin(GL_POLYGON)` ... `glEnd()` snippet in a `for` loop that renders the appropriate number of hexagons.

To adjust the size of a hexagon, you need to adjust the values that you pass into `glVertex3f`.  In your original post, you're drawing a hexagon that's contained in a circle of radius one (since the coefficients to your `sin` and `cos` functions is also one).  If you use a smaller radius (i.e., a value less than one), you'll get a smaller hexagon.

Finally, each of your hexagons is currently centered at the origin.  To move them to a different place within your viewing area of [-1,1] in x and y, merely add offsets to the x and y coordinates that you pass into `glVertex3f`.  Since each hexagon will presumably have its own offset, you'll probably want to use an array sized for the number of hexagons, and index that by your outer loop.

Comment: I wouldn't even start to argue if this is fast or not, it is just outright deprecated functionality.

Comment: @GlenMorse Vertex Buffer Objects.

Comment: @radical7 i have done pretty much what you suggested. but its only giving me one row no matter what offset i put for the collumn. Anyhow i have updated code , should i add it here or make new question?

Comment: @pmr Sure it's slow (with respect to graphics performance) and it's deprecated, but this is a fine way to get started with the problem.  However, I suspect it's faster for Glen Morse to get something going than trying to explain VBOs, shader plumbing, and all that.  If compatibility profiles were so horrible, I'm sure [NVIDIA would change their tune](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/GTC/PDF/GTC2012/PresentationPDF/SS104-Open-GPU-Utility-ToolkitGL.pdf).